# how to represent relationship value on parent for simple entities

Tags: rest, design-patterns, database-design, redux, normalization

This question is about best practices and design patterns; 
I'm sure i can go with any option depending on app, but i want to develop the backend up to best practices regardless of front app/client current needs are.

what is best practice to follow during API development when a certain resource has a one-many/many-many relation with another resource, is it okay to add columns from one resource into other to represent important column that i'm sure its mandatory needed  ?

```
#Example Database may look like:-
Event{
 id: 1,
 user_id: 1
}
User:{
 id: 1,
 name: 'Momen',
}
```

Now to respond to GET /Post/1

```
## Option 1
Event{
  id:1,
  user_id:1,
  user:{
   id:1,
   name: momen,
  }
}
## Option 2
Events{
1: Event{
  id:1,
  user_id:1,
  user_name: 'momen',// i will not include User object unless client request it.. but i will inject user_name because it's a data i'm sure that Post will always need
}
}
```

the User object in above example can be huge, and i don't want the whole user object, -unless app needs more info about the user- yet i still need his name to display in the list of Events. so is it okay to add this name to Event object as a fallback, so if client dont have access to User:1 in his memory, he can display this column while fetching User.

**Q1** Is this acceptable or i'm polluting Object and introducing anomily bugs ?

in another case of Many-to-Many relation; I have a flag I want to set, should I set it on parent Entity or I have to include relation object as well.

```
EventUser{
 event_id: 1,
 user_id: 1,
}
```

Adding `EventUsers` Link table which represents a one-many relation,

**Q2. I want to set a flag next event that indicates if the user who is querying those events is going to this event or not.**

so in a restful-API, to respond to `GET /events/1` request i can

```
## option 1:

Event{
 id:1,
 name: 'Event 1',
 is_going: true
}

## option 2
{
  events:{ 1:{id:1, name:'Event 1'} },
  EventUser:{1:{ event_id: 1, user_id: 1},} // or {} if not going
}
```

its clear that option1 is easier to implement and easier to deal with.. but this mean that again i'm introducing columns to Event Model that does not exists. plus if the client is going to cache such results for offline-first usage, and user changes then this data is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with api's is that I always get more data then I bargained for and objects are highly decoupled.
In your case I would keep users as an array of independent objects under events and allow over explicit results. You can always add a *fields* optional parameter in the api payload so the user can decide which fields are interesting (on your side implement a obj_res = _.pick(obj, fields) )

Never concatenate the objects, that will lead to a nightmare when your objects change and grow over time. Coupling is bad :)

Comment: even in the 2nd condition where you want to indicate if the user is attending an event or not (linking table)?

Comment: In the 2nd condition it seem that the answer should be *user* centric. I'd return an object style { user : 1234, attending_event: 9876 }